# How do I find the filename of an image on a MediaWiki page using php?

Tags: php, mediawiki

How do I find the filename of an image on a MediaWiki site?
I don't want to put the filename in manually. I need PHP code which will fetch me the filename.
I can use `$f = wfFindFile( '$filename' );` but HOW DO I GET $filename?
I've been looking at the FILE class but I can't figure out how to use `File::getFilename();` I keep getting an error `call to undefined method`.
What am I doing wrong?

Explaining in more detail: 
I would like to add the pin it button to my site so when you click on the button it post it on the pin it board with the image and description of the image. I need to use php to send the image information so it works on every page on my site. I can't code the image name manually each time. 
So far I have the code:

```
        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' . urlencode($f->getFullURL()).'&media='.urlencode($f->getCanonicalUrl() ).'&description='.urlencode($f->getDescription()) .'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
```

Which works great except I need to put in a value for $f (image name). My question is how do I get the value of $f without having to put in in eg $f = wfFindFile( 'Sunset.jpg' );
I would have thought this would be a really common request for anyone trying to add pinterest to their site. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us your code that's causing the error?

Answer (score 4):

The $filename you are looking for is basically how it is named in MediaWiki when it got uploaded, for example Landscape-plain.jpg. You will just use the wfFindFile() helper function to get a File object. Then call the methods:

> $ php maintenance/eval.php
>
> > $file = wfFindFile( 'Landscape-plain.jpg' );
>
> > print $file->getName();
>
> Landscape-plain.jpg
>
> > print $file->getPath();
>
> mwstore://local-backend/local-public/b/b0/Landscape-plain.jpg
>
> > print $file->getFullPath();
>
> /path/to/images/b/b0/Landscape-plain.jpg
>
> > print $file->getTitle();
>
> File:Landscape-plain.jpg
>
> > exit

API documentation:

- http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classFile.html
- http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classLocalFile.html

**EDIT BELOW**

The file informations are available through a File object, so you definitely need to use wfFindFile() to get such an object.

To actually find the filename for the page the user is browsing on, you want to use the query context and get its title:

```
$context = RequestContext::getMain();
$t = $context->getTitle();


if( $title->getNamespace == 'NS_FILE' ) {
  $filename = $title->getPrefixedText;
 // do your stuff.
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't want to have to type in the filename. How do I use php to read the page information, find an image on the page and fill in the filename. I can't type in Landscape-plain.jpg, I have too many pages and images that are changing. I need it to be automatic.

Comment: What about describing what you want to do? :-)

Comment: I am trying to add a pinit button to my site. When you click on the button I want the image name and description to be sent in the URL. I have the code from the pinterest site but I would like to make it so it works for every page and I don't need to put the image information in manually each time. (eg facebook like does this with opengraph).